# Is it possible to prevent textboxes of a continuous form from changing size by changing the record?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Image below shows the problem: 
textboxes change size when changing records in a ms-access form

Is it possible to prevent it?

Thanks in advance

[image: Two states in two registers]

Comment: That is odd. Never seen this. This looks like design issue, not programming, and therefore not really suited to SO. Unless there is some code changing textbox widths, I really don't know why this would happen.

Comment: Is incredible. I've eight forms working fine, the problem is in design time, but I can not identify it.

is it possible that textboxes has any property as "can grow" or "can shrink"?

Comment: CanGrow and CanShrink work for height and on report, not form. Weirdness is often due to corruption that cannot be fixed except by rebuilding - textboxes and/or form.

Comment: I've had quirks like this before. I've created a new Form from scratch, copied over the VBA/Macros and then rebuilt the controls and lo and behold it works. I've also copied over the existing controls/form and have the quirk carry over. It's almost certainly a Microsoft-side oversight that will be impossible to track down. I'd rebuild the form as suggested and try not to think about it!

Comment: I have to do it? :)
Thanks, RazorKillBen, not another way